# How do you implement google Analytics to tack a link click

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to set up google analytics to track when someone clicks a link. This is what I have so far:

This is in the HEAD

```
 <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments) };
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-CODEHERE-2');
</script>
```

Then in my HTML I have this?

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Click', 'CV Pack Download', 'CV Zip Downloads'])" href="path/file.pdf">Download now</a>
```

When I click the link I am getting

```
_gaq is undefined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you read this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?

Comment: You could try putting the (Google Analytics `<script>`) in the `<body>` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an older syntax based on the Classic GA library, ga.js, which has been deprecated. The new syntax can be found here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events. You should have something like this:

`... onclick="gtag('event', 'CV Pack Download', {'event_category': 'Click', 'event_label': 'CV Zip Downloads'});" ...`

where the signature is:

`gtag('event', 'event_name', {
  'event_category': categoryName,
  'event_label': labelName
});`